# Javascript trying to write HTML character code to page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using `.innerHTML` to write strings to an HTML page. I need to have things like `&lt;` and `&gt;` to print alongside `<` and `>` on the page. However, `&lt;` consistently gets printed out as `<`. I've heard that I can do this if I write to the page as HTML rather than text, but I thought `.innerHTML` was doing that. Is there an escape character I can use or is there something I can do with JS to get this done?

Comment: Have you tried `document.write()`? Also, `&amp;`

Comment: @gordon He looks to be trying to go in the other direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write out `&lt;` as `&amp;lt;`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and easy solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<pre>&lt;</pre>` and `<pre>&rt;</pre>` tags in your  `HTML` output .. This should give you the output you are looking for.

Comment: This just added a line between the < and the tag it should surround.

Comment: I would suggest posting more code then so that we all may have a better grasp of what you are attempting to do.

Comment: Michael got it. Thanks, though!

Comment: Er... `<pre>` tags do not prevent HTML entities from working.